# Possibility for a server to ensure WCF service is accessible to endpoint

Tags: windows, web-services, wcf

I have hosted a WCF service in a server and I have 500+ endpoints(PCs) listening and consuming the service by running an executable as windows-service in all those endpoints.

Problem: Some PCs are unable to access the service. From the server side I will have to check and find the reason for this; whether the failure is because of inaccessible of the service or endpoint failures (like the network or any other reason).

Is there any possibility do to the same from server?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility do to the same from the server?

No, not for everything.

If a client can't connect to your server because of network outages, configuration issues or strange middleboxes, there wouldn't be any traces at the server side. AKA no packet from the client will reach the server - so the server doesn't know that someone sent some. If you *know* that exact client, you *could* ping/trace it from the server, but in general, you don't know that.

You can, however, monitor your clients connections; if the client connects successfully to your service, you can log errors from there on in the service itself.